# Run JMeter headless with maven with AMQP plug in

Tags: maven, rabbitmq, jmeter, amqp

I need to run JMeter headless in maven. I've read articles out there that describe how to add jmeter as a maven dependency but what if that JMeter script relies on a 3rd party plug in, namely https://github.com/jlavallee/JMeter-Rabbit-AMQP, then how do I integrate this? Because this is a jar file that is built and put in the JMeter lib/ext dir as a plug in to JMeter? It is not in the maven repo.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See [Adding additional libraries to the classpath](https://github.com/Ronnie76er/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-additional-libraries-to-the-classpath) from JMeter Maven plugin wiki

According to the guide adding something like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
    <artifactId>swingx</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/ext/JMeterAMQP.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

to `pom.xml` should solve your problem.

Also see [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide for details on Maven plugin and more options, perhaps it worth considering running [JMeter via Ant Task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/) if AMPQ plugin is being built with Apache Ant.